# Prove existence of traversal in case subset has a traversal

Tags: combinatorics

The family of sets $(X_1, \dots, X_r, \dots, X_n) $ has a traversal. From this traversal, we can construct a traversal $x_1, \dots, x_r$ on the subfamily of sets $(X_1, \dots, X_r)$.

Question:

Is this reversible? Given a traversal $x_1, \dots, x_r$ on
$(X_1, \dots, X_r, \dots, X_n) $, if we know $X $ has a valid traversal, can we construct a traversal of $X$ that contains $x_1, \dots, x_r$?

Note: $x_i$ doesn't have to be a representative of $X_i, i=1, \dots, r, $in that traversal.

I don't know how to proof it. Can anybody give me a hint?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @caduk, I can't proof this condition

Answer (score 0):

We first relabel $x_1,\dots,x_r$ so that $x_i$ is in $X_i$.

We know $\mathcal{X}$ has a valid traversal. Take a traversal $\mathcal{T}$ on $\mathcal{X}$.

We construct a traversal on $X_1,\dots,X_r$.

For $i \in\{1,\dots,r\}$, if $x_i$ appears in the subtraversal of $\mathcal{T}$ on the subfamily $X_{r+1},\dots,X_n$, pick the element corresponding to $X_i$ on $\mathcal{T}$. If it did not appear, pick $x_i$.

Combine this traversal with the subtraversal on the subfamily $X_{r+1},\dots,X_n$ and we have a traversal on $\mathcal{X}$ that contains $_1,…,_$.